# Подставить id в url

Tags: javascript

Пишу скрипт в Tampermonkey.

Проблема в там что в адресной строке, при переходе на другую страницу меняется id в url.
Пример

```
https://..../id/454598/...../
```

Записываю url в переменную

```
var currentURL = location.href;
```

Вопрос как мне подставить id с url в `// @match`?

Пробовал так, не сработало

```
// @match        *://.../id/${currentURL }/.../
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно, можете привести полный пример до и после замены, чтобы было понятнее.

Comment: Заграница загрузились с url например https://test.ru/id/458/ и скрипт работает, но при переходе на страницу например https://test.ru/id/477 скрипт уже не будет работать так как в //@match записан url https://test.ru/id/458/. Вот вопрос как подставить id  с переменной currentURL в url который записав в //@match

Comment: `test.ru/id/*`, не?

Comment: Почитал документацию https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns и понял. Спасибо